# How to compute the "jump", using the divergence theorem,

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Given the vector field on $R^3$∖{0},

**F(x)=$(x/r^3,y/r^3,z/r^3)$**, where $r=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac {1}{2}}$,

let R be a simply connected bounded region, with smooth boundary, in the xy plane containing the origin.

Define for ϵ>0,

$h(ϵ)=∬_RF(x−ϵk)⋅kdS(x)$, where the integral is taken over the region R and k is the unit vector perpendicular to the xy plane.

**Compute the jump: $lim_{ϵ↓0}(h(ϵ)−h(−ϵ))$**

The hint given in the problem is: Use the divergence theorem in a punctured cap.

My work:  First off, the final answer is supposed to be  $-4\pi$ , so I am trying to work out the details to show it.

I computed the divergence to be zero -- so F is divergence-free.

Then, since the divergence theorem states that:

$$\int \int_R F.ndS = \int\int\int_{R+\epsilon \bigcup R-\epsilon} (\nabla.F)dV $$

then I am guessing that we can deform *both* the surface R and the volume it encloses, $R+/-\epsilon$, since the right-hand side of the integration yields zero, since F is divergence-free?  So perhaps we can deform the volume to a unit-sphere and work from there to compute $h(\epsilon)$ and subsequently the limit $lim_{ϵ↓0}(h(ϵ)−h(−ϵ))$.

**There are some issues, however:**
At the origin, the vector field blows up.  So, since F is not continuously differentiable, the divergence theorem does not apply.  I know that the hint says to apply the Theorem in a punctured cap, but I am not sure how to do this.

Finally, this is actually part (b) of the problem statement.  For part(a), I computed $$\int\int_{|x|=1} F.ndS = 4\pi,$$

using n = 1/r (x,y,z) as my outward unit-normal, and integrating in spherical-polar coordinates.

I am guessing part(b) likely uses part(a).  (That's why I am wondering whether I can deform the volume into a unit-sphere.)

Any hints or solutions are welcome.

Thanks,